# JQuery Javascript Filtering Array By Latest Distinct Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filtering

Thank you in advance for any help/advice.

I have an array object shown below.

```
{
    "DogName": "Max",
    "DogBreed": "GermanShepherd"
},
{
    "DogName": "Blitz",
    "DogBreed": "GoldRet"
},
{
    "DogName": "Max",
    "DogBreed": "Shitzu"
}
```

I am looking to filter this array to only show distinct values based on the last entry "DogName".

Therefore, the resulting array would look like this

```
{
    "DogName": "Blitz",
    "DogBreed": "GoldRet"
},
{
    "DogName": "Max",
    "DogBreed": "Shitzu"
}
```

Been trying for an hour with the foreach / inarray functions but not having much luck.

Your time is appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for a one-liner?

```
// Your dogs array
const dogs = [
{
    DogName: "Max",
    DogBreed: "GermanShepherd"
},
{
    DogName: "Blitz",
    DogBreed: "GoldRet"
},
{
    DogName: "Max",
    DogBreed: "Shitzu"
}];

// Use a Map to store unique dog objects by your desired key (e.g. DogName)
const filteredDogs = [...new Map(dogs.map(dog => [dog["DogName"], dog])).values()];
```

Hope it works!